# Android layout scale with device dpi

Tags: android-studio, layout, dpi

I've created a basic layout. However, it is broken on my high-dpi device. How to center the whole layout?
[image: layout in editor.]
[image: layout on device.]

Comment: Can you put it all in a relative Layout and center it?

Comment: Create layout which will contain all your views that need to be centered. Set that layout width and height to wrap_content and put it in RelativeLayout with android:layout_centerInParent="true"